# Are there negative tags that should not appear in <head> as far as Google is concerned?

Tags: seo, google-search, meta-tags

I just created a new website and I put quite a few `meta` and `link` elements in the `head` element.

Looking at various posts on the net, it seems that some say certain `meta` or `link` tags can have a negative impact. Or the fact that you have *so many* can somehow impact you SEO ranking. The only one I know of, that can have a negative effect, is the `keywords` meta tag in the event you put keywords that have nothing to do with the page and/or site.

From what I find at Google, there isn't much about those tags. I have seen [this page](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/79812?hl=en), for example, which lists a few tags that they support. But I have not seen a more authoritative page where they list the entire set of tags they support there. (i.e. `canonical`, `next`, `prev`, …).

What I'd like to make sure of is that there are no black listed tags. Correct?

Comment: Invalid tags or text has no negative impact within the head unless it damages the rendering of your page... Google and Bing cares very little about your code... why it would they care? after all, visitors see your content, not your code and search engines tailor results for users and does not favour picture perfect coded websites.

Comment: The `keywords` meta tag is unlikely to have a _negative effect_, as most search engines (including Google) simply ignore it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google for a long while now has placed very little credit in meta tags in favor of evaluating the page content itself. I am not aware of any particular meta tags that can cause a negative effect on a sites tank but that isn't to say there is none, Google evaluates a site based on a huge number of signals (somewhere around 2000 if memory serves) and the meta tags basically account for a relatively tiny contribution against other signals such as content, load time, user experience, etc.